# How to get the integer value of a factor with mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, levels

I am trying to use `dplyr::mutate()` to return the integer value of the level of a factor column for each row. Here's what I have so far:

```
a <- tibble(group = factor(c(rep(c('group1', 'groupA', 'groupB'), 4), rep('groupC', 3))),
            name1 = factor(c(rep(c('gene1', 'gene2', 'geneA', 'geneB'),3), 
                             c('gene1', 'gene2', 'geneA'))),
            name2 = factor(c(rep(c('geneB', 'geneA', 'gene2', 'gene1'), 3),
                             c('geneB', 'geneA', 'gene2')))) %>%
  arrange(group)

a <- group_by(a, group) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number(),
         n_max = max(n),
         lev1 = which(levels(a$name1) == name1))
```

which causes the error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `lev1` must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 2
```

but if I just run `which(levels(a$name1) == 'gene2')` I get the desired value `2`.

What is causing this error and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after this?

```
group_by(a, group) %>%
    mutate(
        n = row_number(),
        n_max = max(n),
        lev1 = as.numeric(name1))
## A tibble: 15 x 6
## Groups:   group [4]
#   group  name1 name2     n n_max  lev1
#   <fct>  <fct> <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 group1 gene1 geneB     1    4.    1.
# 2 group1 geneB gene1     2    4.    4.
# 3 group1 geneA gene2     3    4.    3.
# 4 group1 gene2 geneA     4    4.    2.
# 5 groupA gene2 geneA     1    4.    2.
# 6 groupA gene1 geneB     2    4.    1.
# 7 groupA geneB gene1     3    4.    4.
# 8 groupA geneA gene2     4    4.    3.
# 9 groupB geneA gene2     1    4.    3.
#10 groupB gene2 geneA     2    4.    2.
#11 groupB gene1 geneB     3    4.    1.
#12 groupB geneB gene1     4    4.    4.
#13 groupC gene1 geneB     1    3.    1.
#14 groupC gene2 geneA     2    3.    2.
#15 groupC geneA gene2     3    3.    3.
```

`name1` is already a `factor`, so `as.numeric` returns its factor level index.

Comment: i guess `as.integer` is more appropriate

Comment: Yes! I was hoping there would be something that straightforward.

Comment: @MichaelChirico True; or we can also use `unclass(name1)`.

Comment: as `as.integer` is primitive I've found it to be faster than `unclass` sometimes! surprising to me but i also like that it's more readable in code :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Interesting. Since `as.numeric` is also primitive, I wonder how `as.numeric` compares. I remember reading about `as.numeric` in Hadley's Advanced R, and that things were complicated...but perhaps I remember wrongly.

Comment: i tried replicating the example data here 10 million times (150,000,000 rows in output), and all three versions (`as.integer`, `as.numeric`, `unclass`) took less than  1 second to complete even on the huge data. `unclass` is fastest, `as.integer` very close 2nd, and `as.numeric` about half the speed of `as.integer`. anyway, even for RAM-threateningly large data, the speed is very fast.

Comment: @MichaelChirico interesting and thanks for the benchmark.

Comment: it's a pretty off-the-cuff one; a more representative case would probably be to make sure the number of levels of `name1` is growing since I imagine this will have an effect